# PayPal Rest SDK API - Get Token

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am truly stumped here; trying to use the PayPal REST api and cannot even get the access token. When using CURL ([example](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-curlsamples/blob/master/execute_all_calls.php)), the token is created fine so I know the Client ID and Secret are OK.

When I use the code below with the PHP libraries, I get null's for access token in JSON Response.

```
require_once('/home/admin/vendor/autoload.php');

$host = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com';
$clientId = <CLIENT_ID>;
$clientSecret = <CLIENT_SECRET>;

use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox"
);

$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential(
    $clientId,
    $clientSecret,
    $sdkConfig
);

var_dump($cred);
```

var_dump JSON Response:
"accessToken":"PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential":private]=> NULL

Comment: That's not a JSON response, it's an `Object` dump. Now, at the point you've got to, you don't need for `$cred` to have the access token, it will get generated later automatically if I remember correctly once you've started doing actual calls or potentially when you set up the API Context object.

Comment: Jon, according to their integration guide https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/pay_paypal/php?interactive=ON&env=sandbox ,the token should be in the reponse.

Comment: Their integration guide is, frankly, useless. In a couple of places it's also plain wrong (or perhaps just not up-to-date).

Comment: We have added a lot of interesting SDK specific documents at http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/. To be specific, you could easily follow steps provided here to get hang of our sdk: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call. We also have a lot of samples that you could see here: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/ and run in your local machine using one command mentioned following instructions at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at [the SDK code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), the `OAuthTokenCredential` constructor method doesn't take a `$config` parameter but the `getAccessToken()` method does.

Here are the methods from the [`OAuthTokenCredential`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php) class code:

```
public function __construct($clientId, $clientSecret) { ... }

public function getAccessToken($config) { ... }
```

The following should get an access token for you:

```
$clientId = <CLIENT_ID>;
$clientSecret = <CLIENT_SECRET>;

use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox"
);

$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential(
    $clientId,
    $clientSecret
);

$access_token = $cred->getAccessToken($sdkConfig);

echo $access_token;
```